# View is clipped during presentModalViewController transition animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have initialized a UIViewController with a nib file which displays fine when I push it on my viewstack.

However when I try and present it as a modal viewcontroller, the view of that controller is clipped at the bottom during the transition animation only. After the transition is done, the view displays just fine.

Anyone have a clue what is going on here? Do I need to set additional properties on my viewcontroller that is presenting my modal viewcontroller?
I have tried re-setting the frame of my viewcontroller without success...